trouble with "S3 method for class 'formula'" when working with qda()
I'm trying to fit a Quadratic Discriminant Analysis, using qda in MASS. When I try it, I get one of two different error messages, depending on whether I put the formula in the call to qda or define the formula first (MRE below). Although the errors are different, they both look like qda is assuming that I'm using the 'Default S3 method' or the 'S3 method for class 'matrix', rather than the formula method.   Can you help?  How can I get qda to recognize that I'm trying to use the method for class 'formula'?  Or am I missing something about what is causing the issue?
More details, and a MRE:
library(MASS) 
data = tibble(Outcome = c(rep("in", 30), rep("out", 80)),
Pred1 = sample(30:80, 110, replace = T),
Pred2 = sample(c(rep("up", 80), rep("down", 30))))
model.qda <- data %>% 
qda(Outcome ~ Pred1 + Pred2, 
data = data)

  

"Error in qda.default(x, grouping, ...) :
nrow(x) and length(grouping) are different"
A different attempt:
myformula <- Outcome ~ Pred1 + Pred2
model.qda <- data %>% 
qda(formula = myformula, 
data = data)

"Error in qda.default(x, grouping, ...) :
argument "grouping" is missing, with no default"

When you pipe in the data, like data %>% qda(...., it gets injected into the first argument. For your first example, you effectively writing qda(x = data, grouping = Outcome ~ Pred1 + Pred2, data = data). This means S3 dispatching occurs on data, not on your formula. Write model.qda <- qda(Outcome ~ Pred1 + Pred2, data = data), or model.qda <- qda(myformula, data = data)

model.qda = data |> qda(Outcome ~ Pred1 + Pred2, data = _) and
model.qda = data %>% qda(formula = Outcome ~ Pred1 + Pred2, data = .) both do work. Note that there is no reason to use {tidyverse}here at all.
